# Running python script in trace mode where only non-internal code-lines are printed to the screen

Tags: python, debugging

I'm running a python script from a complex installer bundle and I'd like to observe the code lines of my own code. However, using the `trace` option I not only get my own code lines being executed, but the entire internal code of the built-in python frameworks.

For example, consider the following simple script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -m trace -t

import base64


print("start")
x = "aaaaa"
y = base64.b64encode(x)
print("end "+y)
```

in this case, instead of just printing the 4 lines of code, I get all lines which occur within `base64.b64encode`. is there any configuration to print only my own code lines ?

UPDATE : I've found an option to ignore specific modules using the `--ignore_module` option, but I'm looking for the opposite way, to allow only specific files or directories for being traced.